# Plotting a histogram with ggplot with only x values and frequency count, instead of usual frequency vector

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a dataframe for my for variable X, with the corresponding count of how many times each X value appears:

```
   df = data.frame(X, count.X)
```

I cannot create a frequency vector via

```
      for(i in 1:length(X))  rep(X[i], count.X[i])
```

since the total count is around 37 million and memory allocation becomes an issue. 
I would like to make a histogram with the variable X on the x axis of the histogram, and count.X in the frequency bars , however I cannot seem to find how to do this as everything seems geared towards plotting frequency vectors.

Thanks :)

Comment: What you want is called a barplot. ggplot2 has a corresponding geom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use stat="identity" with geom_bar.

e.g.

```
testdt <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), count = c(10, 20, 10, 5, 15, 25))
ggplot(data = testdt) + geom_bar(aes(x = x, y = count), stat = "identity")
```

Comment: No worries - feel free to mark it as the correct answer if it works for you.